# Apply the left margin on text that wraps when using a DL

Tags: html, css

I can't change the html on this but can edit the css and need to style it to match an existing site. On the existing site they have no titles long enough to wrap. But now they do.

I have a DL with a link inside the DT. I am using the :before element to apply an arrow > and all works great except when the text wraps down to multiple lines it does not align correctly.

I would like the text on the 2nd row (and all others if the text grows) to align with the first row. I want the arrow to stand out on it's own no matter how much text is to the right of it.

```
<dl class="clearfix">
<dt class="title">
    <a href="#">The Art of Lauhala (Pandanus Leaf) Weaving by Pohaku Kahoohanohano - Honokohau, Maui</a> 
</dt>
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdpdj0er/1/)

Comment: Just pasting that small snippet of code would be so much easier than describing it.

Comment: pad the DL, float the arrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your CSS like this:

```
dl {
    margin: 0;
}
dt {
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    width:calc(100% - 15px)
}
dl:before {
    vertical-align:top;
    content:"> ";
    display: inline-block;
    width:10px;
}
```

**Explanation:**

I gave both elements an `inline-block` property then a width to `dl:before` of 10px. Since I don't know the width of the container, I assumed 100%, but that would give me 100% + 10px of that `dl:before` so I added a [***calc* property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) with an additional 5px to play safe, hence `width:calc(100% - 15px)`

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zxcm4cxu/) and play around with values

Comment: Fabio that's perfect! Thanks very much.